npm install curl error 35 : failed to receive handshake, SSL/TLS connection failed
When I try to execute this curl command: curl https://registry.npmjs.org/npm
I get the following error:
curl: (35) schannel: failed to receive handshake, SSL/TLS connection failed
I already installed a completely new curl version and didnt work. Also, I dont have any firewall restrictions.
I have searched this error online and haven't found an answer.
